# GWT + ArrayList + Server Side

Tags: java, gwt

I am developing an application in GWT.
In server side had a method that returns an arraylist. In client side, when i invoke the method, gets onFailure.

> ```
> public void onFailure(Throwable caught){
> label.setText("ERROR");
> }
> public void onSuccess(ArrayList<partner> result){
> // do something
> }
> ```

The label gets "ERROR"!

Anyone knows why?

Cumps!

Comment: Use label.setText(caught.getMessage());  What does it say? Which IDE do you use?

Comment: Netbeans... it says:"500 The call failed on the server; see server log for details"

Comment: well, then, see server logs then... There's evidently some error there.

Comment: GWT Hosted Mode Window - jetty server would have logged some error. If you are using GPE launch file then see GPE console for logs. Attach them in your question. Also attach what e.printStackTrace() shows.

Comment: You should debug the method on the server side and have a look at your console. Also your client will not know what happend on the server side,until you make a new RPC Call. The client just know that the rpc call failed. You could store the exception in the current session and read it back if your first method fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArrayList is not a [transportable](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory#transportable) type. You must use List instead.